# Git Gui not working

Tags: git, tortoisegit

git not displaying correct icons. Instead of green it is displaying blue. Also I not able initiate any commands via context menu( Git Gui) hence I am  doing actions via cmd line for example: git clone

Comment: blue should mean "locally modified" (https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-wcstatus.html). Also, for the menu, would https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=1995 help?

Comment: I installed and downloaded code for the first time. When I tried via Git GUI, I am getting following error:git.exe clone   --progress -v  "ssh://sxxxx-git1//data/git/SXXXXXX/TMXXX_App.git" "C:\xxx\TMxxx_App"

Cloning into C:\xxxx\TMxxx_App...
error: cannot spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork

Comment: Please be more precise. Git GUI is not TortoiseGit and TortoiseGit has nothing to do with TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 1):

> When I tried via Git GUI, I am getting following error:

```
 git.exe clone --progress -v "ssh://sxxxx-git1//data/git/SXXXXXX/TMXXX_App.git" "C:\xxx\TMxxx_App" Cloning into C:\xxxx\TMxxx_App... error: 
 cannot spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin: No such file or directory 
 fatal: unable to fork
```

If the path is either not found, or not accessible (for a right issue), you can:

- download the latest git archive [`PortableGit-2.5.1-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.5.1.windows.1/PortableGit-2.5.1-64-bit.7z.exe) (to uncompress in a simple path like `C:\prgs\PortableGit-2.5.1-64-bit`)
- use that path (`C:\prgs\PortableGit-2.5.1-64-bit\bin`) in the [TortoiseGit config](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html) "`Git.exe path`":

[image: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/images/SettingsMain.png]

Comment: I repaired git and it is working as expected but the icons are still in blue

Comment: @Venu can you post a screenshot?